# Javascript IDE errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, intellij-idea, ide

I'm not sure how to to explain this problem, so I can't really find any solutions on Google. I am new to the whole Javascript world and its technologies.

I am using NodeJS + Express + Jade to make a web application, I got this project from my colleague. But somehow my IDE keeps saying statement or expression expected everywhere.

[image: ide problem]
[image: ide problem]

Comment: You can't name fat-arrow functions, they are anonymous.  Looks like you've missed a colon in `getCompany(apiBaseUrl, companyId) => {...`

Comment: @Emissary: he's using an object, not a named function.

Comment: @marvinhagemeister exactly - look at the first image (it reads like a named function when it should be property).

Comment: @Emissary: you're right, missed that on the tiny screenshot!

Comment: the first function is also closed with a semi-colon after it instead of a comma which will be error number two - please read up on javascript syntax, as it stands this issue is just the result of typos.

Comment: I will be reading up some documentation on the syntax, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE linter for javascript doesn't understand recent javascript features like arrow functions. Make sure your IDE supports Ecmascript 6.

Comment: The problem was indeed the Ecmascript, it was not on 6. Thanks!